# Android Gradle Issue: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: android, gradle, exception, build, version

My project is not building never. I got the same error all time.

I tried for a day to some other solutions but I couldn't progress :/

I searched the solution and I realized that it may be related to maven.

By the way, my project is old.

here Is the error message;

[image]

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_1tiyt7a69ra5smonjfai0v39h.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1tiyt7a69ra5smonjfai0v39h$_run_closure2) values: [build_1tiyt7a69ra5smonjfai0v39h$_run_closure2@2cca4753]
at build_1tiyt7a69ra5smonjfai0v39h.run
```

My **build.gradle (app)** file is below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/journeyapps/maven"; allowInsecureProtocol = true }
    }
}

repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        flatDir { dirs "libs" }
    }


android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.boomset.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 21
        compileSdkVersion 30
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 60000013
        versionName "6.1.3"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 2
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
 
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField("int", "PLATFORM", platform)
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"${endpoint}\""
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL_PRETEST", "\"${pretest_endpoint}\""
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL_STAGING", "\"${staging_endpoint}\""
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField("int", "PLATFORM", platform)
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"${endpoint}\""
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL_PRETEST", "\"${pretest_endpoint}\""
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL_STAGING", "\"${staging_endpoint}\""
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
//        lintOptions {
//            disable 'InvalidPackage'
//        }

        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }
    }


    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'gson'
    }

    configurations.all {
        c -> c.resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
                if (dependency.requested.group == 'org.bouncycastle') {
                    dependency.useTarget 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.69'
                }
            }
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '1.0.0'
    retrofitVersion = '2.4.0'
    okhttp3Version = '3.10.0'
    rxjava2Version = '2.2.1'
    butterKnifeVersion = '10.1.0'
    leakCanary = '1.5.4'
    ormlite = '4.48'
}


dependencies {

//dependencies...

}
```

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file also

Comment: Prefer self-answer than edit and add the naswer in your question

Comment: Did you fixed it ? Im facing the same problem after updating my android studio

Comment: I fixed already but I don't remember it clearly, as I remember I removed some file (cache file) in .gradle directory

Comment: Do u have solution for this issue ,if please can u update the fix.

Answer (score 4):

If you were making some changes to proguard recently.
Look for line that sets **useProguard** false/true and **DELETE** this because it's no longer supported

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? Im facing the same error after updating my android studio to the latest version .

Answer (score -1):

the problem is in build.gradle in android{} tag components

Comment: this actuall is the right direction (before this you could try to upgrad com.android.tools.build:gradle higher)